# Beginner bash: How can I use the output of echo in a string comparison test?

Tags: linux, bash

What I am trying to do is get the output of echo, and then, do a string comparison. 
Example:

```
var=echo "Some string"

if [ var = "* string" ]
then
echo true
else
echo false
fi
```

Here's another attempt:

```
if [ (echo "Some string") = "* string" ]
then
echo true
else
echo false
fi
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Note that capturing the output of echo is generally pointless -- you're taking a shell string ("Some string"), having echo write it as output, then capturing that output and turning it back into a shell string.  Why bother?  That is, instead of `var="$(echo "Some string")"`, just use `var="Some string"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use command substitution:

```
var=$(echo "Some string")
if [ "$var" = "* string" ]
```

or:

```
if [ "$(echo "Some string")" = "* string" ]
```

Note the double-quotes that I added. They're important, because otherwise Bash will split things up into multiple words; `[ Some string = "* string" ]` will not work. For this reason, and other related ones, I recommend using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, which is less strict about that:

```
if [[ $(echo "Some string") = "* string" ]]
```

though it actually sounds like you want:

```
if [[ $(echo "Some string") == *" string" ]]
```

which will perform a pattern match rather than comparing the strings for *exact* equality.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if [ `echo "Some string"` = "* string" ]; then
(other commands)
fi
```

or alternatively,

```
if [ $(echo "Some string") = "* string" ]; then
(other commands)
fi
```

Note that you will also need a semicolon *before* the `then` keyword.

Comment: "...semicolon before the 'then' keyword" - Or a newline.